# CouchDB cookie authentication / overcoming Safari Third Party Rules

Tags: safari, couchdb, session-cookies

I have been struggling with CouchDB Authentication. My web application is running at https://aaa.com and my CouchDB is at https://bbb.com:6984 so I am accessing CouchDB using JS fetch. When I POST a _session login I do get a set-Cookie header on the response, and most browsers like Chrome comply and add the cookie to the bbb.com website. All except Safari.

I understand this is to avoid 3rd party tracking etc. My question is; what is the "typical" or "recommended" deployment according to CouchDB developers? I would have thought this is a very typical scenario where App server speaks with an API or DB server somewhere else.

Now If I am forced to call everything from the same server, what are the minimum requirements for App vs DB server? Which should work in Safari?

```
   App Server           CouchDB
1) BBB.com:5000         BBB.com:6984
2) xxx.BBB.com          BBB.com:6984
3) xxx.BBB.com          yyy.BBB.com
4) BBB.com              BBB.com:6984
```

Thanks